# Existence of a space $X$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |\langle x,e_k \rangle|^2 < \|x\|^2 $?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Recall that

> **Theorem (Bessel inequality).** Let $(e_k)$ be an orthonormal sequence in an inner product space $X$. Then for every $x \in X $, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |\langle x,e_k \rangle|^2 \le \|x\|^2 .$$

The proof results in $\le$ and not just $=$. Can $\le$ be 'reduced' to $=$? And if so, how? By example searching I couldn't find any space $X$ such that the relation is just $<$.

For some sapces that I knew, e.g. $X=\mathbb{R^n}$, equality holds. Is there any space such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |\langle x,e_k \rangle|^2 < \|x\|^2 ?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Hilbert space, $\sum_0^\infty |\langle x, e_k\rangle|^2 = \|P(x)\|^2$ where $P$ is the orthogonal projection on the closed linear span of the $e_k$ and one has
$$P(x) = \sum_0^\infty \langle x, e_k\rangle e_k$$
This closed linear span can be smaller than the whole space. Take any orthonormal sequence and remove some $e_k$'s and you have an example.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, the reason is that the number of $(e_k)$'s is infinite even after dropping some of them we still have summation from $1$ to $\infty$; which is not working for a finite dimensional case. That is, inequality holds **only** because of not considering some terms $\langle x, e_k\rangle e_k$, otherwise it's always equality. Am I right?

Comment: It is rather the other way round. In a separable Hilbert space any orthonormal family $e_k$ can be completed into a complete orthonormal family by adding another sequence of $e_k$'s.  The family is complete if one cannot add an orthonormal vector. In this case the closed linear span is the whole space. Note that an *inner product space* is more general than a Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

In general, equality holds ([Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity)) when the $e_k$
form a **complete** orthonormal sequence. For instance the $e^{inx}$
for $n\in\Bbb Z$ is a complete orthonormal sequence in $L^2[0,1]$.
If you take a complete orthonormal sequence, and discard an element,
and call that $x$, then $\left<x,e_k\right>=0$ for all elements of
the new sequence, but $\|x\|^2=1$.

Comment: What is the definition for "a complete orthonormal sequence"?

Comment: @Edi You might have a look at [Orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) and [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) on Wikipedia.